# How can I use GSON to serialize an array as a JSON object instead of a JSON array?

Tags: java, arrays, json, serialization, gson

I have a class:

```java
public class Profile {
    private int name;

    // getter and setter
}
```

and this method elsewhere:

```java
public static void printProfiles(Profile[] profiles) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(profiles));
}
```

As expected, I get the following result:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "some name 1"
  },
  {
    "name": "some name 2"
  }
]
```

But I would like the Profile[] array to be serialized as a JSON object instead of as a JSON array, such that each profile in the output JSON has an assigned key for it, and that they're nested in a JSON object instead of an array. Something like this:

```js
{
  "profile1": {
    "name": "some name 1"
  },
  "profile2": {
    "name": "some name 2"
  }
}
```

How would I go about accomplishing this? I'm not very familiar with GSON and couldn't figure out the solution to this by going through the documentation. Thanks in advance!

I've tried creating a Profiles class:

```java
public class Profiles {
    private Profile profile1;
    private Profile profile2;
    // etc
    
    // setters and getters
}
```

and then updating my method:

```java
public static void printProfiles(Profiles profiles) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(profiles));
}
```

which gives the expected results. But this is obviously not a real solution because the number of Profiles varies and can be in the hundreds.

Comment: You have a small typo in your target JSON - it should be `"profile2":` not `"profile2:"`.

Comment: A Java `Map` of `Profile` objects, where the map's keys are `"profile1"`, `"profile2"`, and so on... is a natural fit for what you appear to need.

Comment: @andrewJames You're right, I just fixed that. And also I can't believe I haven't considered just using a Map, that's a great suggestion. Thank you